# How to prevent disk corruption on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, filesystem-corruption

I have a btrfs filesystem with redundant metadata in a virtualbox image. After a host system crash the btrfs partition experienced some corruption, which is counter to the guarantees of the filesystem, which suggests that virtualbox is violating those guarantees.

How do I get VBox to behave?

Comment: What was file system of the host?  The use of btrfs within the virtual hdd only protected the guest OS from causing a file corruption problem it doesn't prevent the corruption of the file itself on the host os.

Comment: @Ramhound the file in the host was fixed-size, pre-allocated and no snapshots. So as long as flush translates to fsync the data should reliably make it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be two solutions

- [disable ignore flush](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#idm10187), this is only available from the command line.

  > virtual ATA device:
  >
  > VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/piix3ide/0/LUN#[x]/Config/IgnoreFlush" 0
  >
  > virtual SATA device:
  >
  > VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#[x]/Config/IgnoreFlush" 0

  where [x] is the 0-indexed drive number for that controller
- [enable the host cache](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/MBS8hCDY8hE) for the virtual controller in question, this can be done in the UI. It has the downside that IO cache inside the VM will likely hold data that will also be in the host cache, thus consuming twice the memory for IO caches.

  reducing `vm.swappiness` in the guest may help here since the page cache is less important if the data is already in the host cache.

Note that it's hard to tell whether each solution is reliable due to the random nature of crashes and corruption.